# Adding Combo box on title bar on runtime

Tags: codenameone

I want to add combo box and a Button on the title bar. which method/code can i use?
 i have tried Form set Title Component(new Combo Box()) but it does not work

```
Form.setTitleComponent(new ComboBox());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work since the title component in Codename One must be a Label subclass. However, the new Toolbar API provides more customizability and would allow you to do just that. See:

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/toolbar

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/cats-in-toolbars